Difference between phenoxypropane and propoxybenzene?
I was revising some of my chemistry where I came across this structure. I do not know which way to name it or the reason it would be correct according to IUPAC standards.
Thank you.

There's no "difference". You can call it how you like.

The longer chain is the base, in this case the phenyl group. The smaller, shorter group becomes the alkoxy substituent.

Why was Willy England's text deleted, and converted to a comment ? It is THE answer to the question...

There are set of guidelines that needs to be followed for answering nomenclature questions: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3066. Otherwise, whatever is written will be either deleted or converted into comment even if it answers the question. @Maurice
